# perl cgi won't access php session data in /tmp

Tags: php, perl, session, cgi

I am trying to gain access to an existing php session from a perl script. I can see sample of php to perl, but not perl to php. My biggest issue is accessing the /tmp directory correctly. I have all the proper permissions, I just cannot find how to capture the session.
I see all of the /tmp/sess~ files but I cannot find anything close to a working example to show me how to get to it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Script to launch the vncserver service and capture output
# Runs, displays $pid to STDOUT, but opened
# files are empty.

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw();
use CGI::Session qw();

my %vars = (
    COOKIE_NAME => '_SESSION',
    SESSION_DIR => '/tmp',
);
my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->header;
CGI::Session->name($vars{COOKIE_NAME});
my $session = CGI::Session->new('id:md5', $q, {Directory=>$vars{'/tmp/'}});

print $session->header(-type => 'text/plain');


my $system_name  = $session->param("_SESSION_ATIME");
print $system_name->output();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways that session data could be stored. PHP uses one way. `CGI::Session` uses another. You can't use `CGI::Session` to read PHP sessions. Use [`PHP::Session`](https://metacpan.org/module/PHP%3a%3aSession) instead.